# How to check if registered variable has a particular pattern in ansible?

Tags: debugging, ansible, conditional-statements, msg

So I want to check if nginx syntax is ok

```
- name: check if syntax is ok on nginx
  shell: nginx -t
  register: result
```

then I want to use that with the service module with "when:" conditional to run the service module to reload nginx "when:" "result" has in it "syntax is ok".

Would something like this work?

```
when: result.stdout_lines == "syntax is ok"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this,

```
when: result.stdout | search("syntax is ok")
```

It will search for the string "syntax is ok" in the `result.stdout` string, and, if it finds it then the condition will result in success and will run the desired task, if it results in failure then the task will be skipped.

I have added few more ways to achieve the same result,

```
when: result.stdout is search("syntax is ok")
```

Use regex_search

```
when: result.stdout | regex_search("syntax is ok")
```

And the one suggested by @TinaC can also be used.

Tested on **ansible version 2.8.0**

**Test ansible playbook**

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - error_msg: "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ error_msg }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ error_msg }}"
      when: error_msg | search("syntax is ok")

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ error_msg }}"
      when: error_msg is search("syntax is ok")

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ error_msg }}"
      when: error_msg | regex_search("syntax is ok")
```

**Output**

```
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.101] => {
    "msg": "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.101] => {
    "msg": "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.101] => {
    "msg": "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.101] => {
    "msg": "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.100.101            : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

When changed the string `syntax is ok` to `syntax is not ok`, below is the output,

```
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.101] => {
    "msg": "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() \"/var/log/nginx/error.log\" failed (13: Permission denied) 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the \"user\" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is not ok 2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() \"/run/nginx.pid\" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.100.101]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.100.101]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.100.101]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.100.101            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @CzipO2, Does it solve your issue, or you are still facing any?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the comment now. TinaC solution works just fine. But I just realized that I have the issue white registering sytnax. When syntax is ok it will register it with "check if syntax is ok on nginx" and then it will proceed, your when probably works too for reloading task. But when syntax is not ok and there is an error it just stop the playbook at "check if syntax is ok on nginx" . Is there a way to force ansible to continue even if it stumbles upon an error? I mean, it's not a big issue, more of an aesthetic since even if it registers that syntax is not ok, the reload won't happen.

Comment: @CzipO2, Yes ignore_errors will work. I have also updated the answer with some more ways to achieve the same results. Any other issue you are facing related to this task?

Comment: Thank you but my playbook is all finished and works fine. One thing you got wrong is that It needs to use result.stderr for some reason. It doesn't work at all with result.stdout.

Comment: @CzipO2, Could you please explain why it doesn't work with `result.stdout`. As per my understanding of the issue, you asked, your task returns `syntax is ok`, and it is returned if the task is executed successfully, Right? So, the string `syntax is ok` will be present in `stdout` and not `stderr`.

Comment: Well when I run ```nginx -t``` on the targeted vm I get this 
```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2019/09/12 16:19:28 [warn] 5343#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2019/09/12 16:19:28 [emerg] 5343#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: it registers that syntax is ok, but it appears that since there were some other errors in the output it put all the lines in stderr. I don't get it. But I guess I should use stdout then.

Comment: OK i fixed nginx so that "nginx -t" comes out with no errors but still stdout doesn't work, only stderr. Also, I tested your way of regex_search and it doesn't work even with stderr.

Comment: @CzipO2, I have added as much info as I can,  you can pick any one of the methods which works for you, whether you use it with `stdout` or `stderr` is up to you, what you can use is what I have shared. Thanks. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
when: "'syntax is ok' in result.stdout_lines"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. when I ``` debug: msg="{{ result.stout_lines }}" ``` it won't msg anything i only works if I change it to ``` "msg={{ result }}" ``` so I used just "result for "when:" and that just skips the task. I change it to {{ result }} instead of ``` result ``` in "when:" and I got a jinja2 templating warning and then an error.

Comment: Well, it works with result.stderr which is weird because that means "Syntax is ok" is part of standard error